# Нужно ли тире после вопроса?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вопрос

Мне нужно употребить в тексте фразу «Подобрать недвижимость? – Легко».

Нужно ли после вопросительного знака ставить тире? Как написать-то?

Comment: Если Вас устроил ответ, проголосуйте за него и пометьте его галочкой как принятый.

Answer (score 3):

В качестве  варианта: **Подобрать недвижимость? Легко!**

Пример рекламы со словом  ***легко***: Ремонт квартиры под ключ – это легко!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но как быть, если я хочу оставить знак вопроса?

Comment: Но в первом варианте есть знак вопроса, этот вариант и используйте. Я привела второй пример, чтобы показать, когда ставится тире.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Вы не обозначили — это слова одного человека или разных людей.

**1.** Если фраза принадлежит одному лицу, то пунктуация будет такой.

В обычном диалоге:
— Ты мне сможешь подобрать недвижимость?
**— Подобрать недвижимость? Легко.**

Если реплики следуют в подбор:
"Ты мне сможешь подобрать недвижимость?" — **"Подобрать недвижимость? Легко".**

**2.** Если слова принадлежат разным лицам, то пунктуация будет такой.

В диалоге:
— Я смогу тебе помочь.
**— Подобрать недвижимость?

— Легко.**

В подбор:
"Я смогу тебе помочь". — **"Подобрать недвижимость?" — "Легко".**

[**§ 52. Знаки препинания при диалоге**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)