# Почему же Господь допускает, чтобы люди страдали и гибли от слова и руки своего ближнего? (–) А Господь не допускает!

Tags: пунктуация, тире, редактура, авторская-пунктуация, корректура

На сайте уже задавался похожий вопрос о том, корректно ли ставить после вопроса тире, когда нет случая диалога ([Нужно ли тире после вопроса?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439698/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)).

- В правилах он нигде не оговаривается, то есть явного запрещения нет. Зато продолжают встречаться тексты со знаком тире после вопроса. Может, можно найти убедительные доводы, позволяющие тире употреблять? Конкретные случаи:

> Почему же Господь допускает, чтобы люди страдали и гибли от слова и руки своего ближнего? – А Господь не допускает!
>
> Ведь если я благочестив и добродетелен, а мой сосед губит свою бессмертную душу, почему моя душа болит за него? – Это заповеданная Господом любовь к ближнему требует молитвы о его спасении...

- Это примеры из текста-рассуждения. Тире здесь имитирует диалог с самим собой: человек рассуждает, задается вопросом и ему приходит ответ. То есть автор как бы задает себе вопрос от читателей/ с читателем и отвечает читателю/себе и читателю. Кажется, в тексте-рассуждении тире в этой функции оправдано. Прямого диалога нет, а есть подразумеваемый (что характерно для этого типа текста), тире обозначает как бы ответную реплику, но без абзаца, так как диалог не явный, тире привносит характерные для диалога интонации при реплике-вопросе и реплике-реакции, и это обогащает текст.
- Подобные случаи встречались у классиков (хотя трудно вспомнить примеры, чтобы это доказать).
- Не припоминаются явное запрещение такого употребления, а в практике употребление встречается.
- Допущение: как авторское употребление знака.

### Как можно решить этот вопрос? Легче всего, конечно, зачеркнуть тире, но количество случаев с тире и просто внутреннее чувство заставляют думать над вопросом.