# Возможно ли после вопроса тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

> В чём же ценность? — в общении, осознании себя как личность, в конце
> концов, в воспитании характера.

Возможно ли такое построение предложения?
Текст не является диалогом.
Могу ли я заменить связку "? —" на двоеточие?

Comment: Без уточнения какого именно характера (свойство поведения человека) — бойца, лидера и т.п. — фраза допускает его отсутствие, что противоестественно. Потому же и слово «приобретение» совершенно неуместно. О словосочетаниях смотрите тут: https://makeword.ru/join/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Спасибо. Это вырвано из текста поэтому смысл может быть не ясен. Хотелось бы всё же знать можно ли ставить после "?" тире. Так же хочу уточнить, что это не диалог. В тексте ведётся повествование. 
Как вариант могу ли я заменить связку "?-" на двоеточие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю оставить вариант с тире и заменить строчную букву второй фразы на заглавную:

***В чём же ценность? — В общении, осознании себя как личность, в конце концов, в воспитании характера.***

Это не противоречит правилу Розенталя:

[ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ЗНАК — ТИРЕ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=193)

> Сопоставим два текста:
> *Что его ждёт впереди? Одни тревоги;
>
> Что его ждёт впереди — одни тревоги.*
> В первом тексте — два предложения, первое заканчивается вопросительным знаком **(после него может быть поставлено тире)**. Во втором тексте — одно бессоюзное сложное предложение с присоединительными отношениями. Оба пунктуационных варианта правомерны.

Я специально выделил жирным вставку в скобках. О замене заглавной буквы в варианте без тире ничего не сказано. И как я думаю, это логично. Вопросительным знаком **заканчивается** одно предложение. А дальше с большой буквы следует ответ-присоединение.

Тире здесь показывает связь двух фраз, первая из которых "обязана" быть с вопросительным знаком, если мы хотим ее выделить интонацией и увидеть на письме (в конце всей структуры он будет далёк и незаметен, и двоеточие здесь не поможет).

В этом тексте идет диалог внутри одной головы, и мы ставим тире между отдельными репликами.

P. S. Ознакомился с вопросом: "[Нужно ли тире после вопроса?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439698/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)" — Всем участникам поставил плюс.

Comment: Александр, скажите, пожалуйста, а в заданном вопросе вторая часть утвердительная или тоже вопросительная? Никак не могу этого понять. А у автора вопроса спросить, наверное, сложно.

Comment: @Sharon  В вопросе в конце знака нет, значит, можно считать, что утвердительная. Если нужен второй вопросит. знак, то можно и его поставить. Но главное здесь то, хочет ли автор подчеркунуть вопрос в первой фразе.

Comment: Если это рассуждение автора (он задает вопрос и он же отвечает), то я написала бы так: В чём же ценность? Она в общении, осознании себя как личность, в конце концов, в воспитании характера. А при постановке тире получается как бы диалог. Как вы думаете? С замечанием Розенталя мне что-то не хочется соглашаться ( "после него может быть поставлено тире"), а примера такого оформления он не привел.

Comment: Конечно, можно и без тире. Но по сути это бессоюзное предложение, в котором первое заканчивается вопросит. знаком.

Comment: Вы думаете, такие отношения можно выразить в БСП? Я сейчас посмотрела Розенталя, там вроде бы  вопросительными должны быть обе части или только последняя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88  Пункт 5.

Comment: Я так думаю, но точно не знаю. Извините, пожалуйста, за боьшое количество вопросов, я действительно затрудняюсь с оформлением  этого предложения.

Comment: Да, грамматически это не одно предложение, т. е. к БСП его не отнести. Но части тесно взаимодействуют друг с другом. С тире или без него – это, как говорится, по наитию. Розенталь не запрещает.

Comment: Александр,  у меня, конечно же,  нет намерений сомневаться в правильности вашего ответа, а плюс я вам давно уже поставила. Вы всегда аккуратны и точны в выборе правила, это ваше достоинство. Но у меня есть претензии к Розенталю, или его редакторам:) Когда я сомневаюсь в правилах «нашего  всего», то виноваты, конечно, они.

Comment: Если честно, то подобное построение, как писал Розенталь, я пару раз видел в художественных произведениях, хоть и сомневался в их правильности, так как это было давно, а память у меня шутки шутит. Поэтому могу сказать, что подобное построение уже используется. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Ferum  И Вам спасибо за вопрос!